# Difference between 'speech', 'talk', 'presentation' and 'story'

Tags: word-choice

I want to speak about my experience abroad and I want to say:

> 1. Today, I'd like to (speak/talk/presentation) about my experience in Denmark.
> 2. Please listen to my (talking/speech/story/presentation) until the end.

Which one is the better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say:

```
Today, I'd like to speak/talk about my experience abroad.

Today, I'd like to show/make a presentation on my experience abroad.

Please listen to my talk/story/presentation until the end.
```

A "speech" (noun) though is usually a directed, formal kind of talk designed to make a point or gather support. "Listen to my speech" (wherein you intended speech to mean talking) wouldn't normally be said - though there is technically nothing wrong with it. Someone might say, "listen to how clear my speech (speaking) is with my new dentures" for example. They might also say, "The minister gave a solemn speech about the increase in crime in his electorate".

Comment: In addition, "story" suggests that it is a speech/talk - in story format. 
Also, "presentation" suggests that it will be 'multi-modal' (e.g. with a powerpoint, music, etc.)

So these two are more selective than a "talk" or "speech".